# Usages de « autant que » et « ainsi que »

Tags: grammaire, adverbes, comparatifs

Je suis encore un débutant en français, mais je comprends l'utilisation normale de « autant que » et « ainsi que ».

Par exemple :

> J'aime le vin rouge autant que le vin blanc.
>
> J'aime le vin rouge ainsi que le vin blanc.

La première phrase peut aussi se dire :

> J'aime le vin rouge et le vin blanc de même.

et la deuxième phrase :

> J'aime le vin rouge. J'aime aussi le vin blanc.

Peut on utiliser « autant que » et « ainsi que » aussi comme cela ?

> Celui-ci coûte autant qu'on pourrait l’espérer.
>
> Je vais à Reykjavík ainsi qu'à Paris cet été.

*Basically, I know the phrases when comparing, but are they also used when not really comparing but instead expressing an idea or multiple actions, respectively?*

Comment: Bienvenu au site ! :) My intuition is that yes, these are fine, even if it might be easier to say « et à Paris » than « ainsi aq'à Paris ». Note that you forgot the liaison (*qu'on*, *qu'à*). Also, often when a verb has a phrasal complement, it's usually represented by a direct object pronoun; in this case, « on l'espère » where the *le* refers to it costing a certain amount. However, I'm not 100% certain these are ideal uses, so I'll leave it to a native speaker to formulate a full answer.

Comment: Given you wrote "peut aussi vouloir dire" (might also mean), can you clarify what difference you make between "J'aime du vin rouge autant que du vin blanc." and "J'aime du vin rouge et du vin blanc les mêmes". Same question about "J'aime du vin rouge ainsi que du vin blanc." vs "J'aime du vin rouge. J'aime aussi du vin blanc." Finally, can you clarify what you mean with "Celui-ci coute autant que on espère."

Comment: I was trying to express my understanding of “autant que” and “ainsi que” by saying the the first phrases could also be said like... probably didn’t express that well but used the words I knew!  The “Celui-ci...” was meant to say “This one here costs as much as one could hope” basically.

Answer (score 3):

*Basically, I know the phrases when comparing, but are they also used when not really comparing but instead expressing an idea or multiple actions, respectively?*

Yes, both can be used these ways.

***Autant*** can be used to express an idea. I'm unsure of the meaning of "it costs as much as one could hope” but a French version might be:

> *Celui-ci coûte autant qu'on pourrait l’espérer.* (i.e. *aussi cher qu'on...*)

I would more expect hoping for a low price though (i.e. "as little as one could hope"):

> *Celui-ci coûte aussi peu (cher) qu'on pourrait l’espérer.*

More idiomatic usage with *autant* applying to an idea might be:

> *Il y a des gâteaux mais pas autant qu'on pourrait l'espérer.*

*Autant* translates *as much as*, *as many*, *as far as* and several other adverbs, e.g.:

> *Autant que je sache, je m'en souvienne* → As far as I know/remember.

***Ainsi que*** can be used to express multiple actions the way you did in the last sentence:

> *Je vais à Reykjavík ainsi qu'à Paris cet été.* → as well as

It's a little formal. In spoken French, as Luke commented, you are more likely to hear :

> *Je vais à Reykjavík et à Paris cet été.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup!  Yeah the “costs as much as one could hope” was contrived, your example of des gâteaux is what I was intending.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**I** « Autant » est un adverbe ; il sert à exprimer la comparaison et il est suivi d'une proposition complétive introduite par « que ».

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autant) I. Adv. de compar. exprimant en phrase compar., explicite ou implicite, l'égalité de deux procès, quant à leur intensité, leur quantité ou leur valeur.
>   A. Autant est suivi d'une prop. complétive, d'un terme de compar. introd. par le corrélatif que.

Dans un contexte particulier « du » peut être utilisé dans vos phrases ; sans certaines indications de ce contexte des  modifications sont nécessaires (« le » au lieu de « du ») pour que le sens soit complet ; de plus d'autres modifications sont nécessaires et sont faites ci-dessous.

*par exemple*

- Avec ce plat de riz, j'aime du vin rouge autant que du vin blanc.

<s>J'aime du vin rouge autant que du vin blanc.</s>                       J'aime le vin rouge autant que le vin blanc.
<s>J'aime du vin rouge ainsi que du vin blanc.</s>                 J'aime le vin rouge ainsi que le vin blanc.
La première phrase peut aussi vouloir dire
<s>J'aime du vin rouge et du vin blanc les mêmes.</s>          J'aime le vin rouge et le vin blanc l'un autant que l'autre.
et la deuxième phrase peut aussi vouloir dire
<s>J'aime du vin rouge. J'aime aussi du vin blanc.</s>          J'aime le vin rouge. J'aime aussi le vin blanc.
<s>Alors, peut on les utiliser aussi comme la suivante?</s>    Alors peut-on utiliser ce mot de la même façon dans d'autres phrases, comme par exemple la suivante ?
<s>Celui-ci coute autant que on espère.</s>                           Celui-ci coute autant que l'on se le figure.

Remarquez que vos phrases sont construite avec une ellipse du verbe ; par exemple vous auriez pu écrire ceci ;

- *J'aime* le vin rouge autant que *j'aime* le vin blanc.

« Ainsi que » est une locution conjonctive, qui dans votre phrase exprime l'addition ; il ne s'agit plus du concept des phrases précédente, lequel était la comparaison.

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ainsi)  Ainsi que, loc. conj. Signifie « de la (même) manière que... », « comme », et peut exprimer, soit la conformité ou la comparaison, soit une idée d'union, d'addition.

<s>Je vais à Reykjavík ainsi que à Paris cet été.</s>                   Je vais à Reykjavík ainsi qu'à Paris cet été.

**II** « Autant » est aussi utilisé avec d'autres sens dans certaines expressions, comme celui-ci expliqué dans le TLFi

> A. [À valeur causale et adversative]
>   1. D'autant plus, d'autant moins, d'autant mieux que ou d'autant que

L'idée de comparaison est remplacé par une idée complexe qui est une combinaison de cause et d'effet adverse ;

- Le contremaitre doit s'en séparer, il ne travaille plus et devient nuisible, d'autant plus que les autres travailleurs prennent exemple sur lui. (ex. de user **LPH**)

cause : il ne travaille plus, devient nuisible
effet adverse :  les autres travailleurs prennent exemple

Ajouté à la nuisance de ne pas travailler on trouve l'effet adverse de donner un mauvais exemple.

Il existe d'autres nuances qui sont expliquées dans le dictionnaire ; si l'un de ces usages n'est pas clair, ne pas hésiter à poser une autre question.

Comment: Merci!  Il me prendra quelque temps pour moi la comprendre! Mais merci pour la réponse complète et les corrections!